# Not able to set spring.datasource.type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, c3p0

I'm trying to setup c3p0 on my spring boot server. This is my config right now

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://url/db
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
#spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
#spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=10000
#spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=30000

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://url/db
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.username=username
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size=7
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time=200
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.url=jdbc:mysql://url/db
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.username=username
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to tell spring.datasource to use

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
```

All XML definitions I saw use something along the lines of

```
<bean id="dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
```

Is it not possible to set the datasource type/class in application.properties?

According to this

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/appendix-application-properties.adoc

there is

```
spring.datasource.type= # fully qualified name of the connection pool implementation to use
```

but according to this

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

(and to my STS) the .type option doesn't exist. Is this a bug or am I supposed to use this differently?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Your `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0` are useless. Spring Boot will inject a datasource which in turn disables the use of these properties, hence they do nothing but add space to your `application.properties`. I would not recommend the usage of C3P0 it  is quite old and has some flaws instead use one of the default supported once like `tomcat-jdbc` or `HikariCP`. That way it is simply a matter of adding the jar and Spring Boot will configure it for you.

Comment: The property you are looking for is for Spring Boot 1.3 earlier versions don't have this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spring.datasource.type` has been introduced in the 1.3 line so you need Spring Boot `1.3.0.M5` to use that property (content assistance in your IDE should have give you the proper hint).

On 1.2.x you need to create the `DataSource` bean yourself to force the type, something like

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
   return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(ComboPooledDataSource.class)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You guys hit the nail on the head. I did my manual setup configuration this morning and hooked up c3p0 but then for one of my controllers I was using jdbcTemplate and it turned out the c3p0 datasource cannot be used with jdbcTemplates so I decided to take a look at the alternatives.

I did some reading and it turned out the tomcat-jdbc pool would be the best option for my case. So to set this up I removed all properties from application.properties that I listed in the original post and added the following custom ones

```
tomcat.jdbc.pool.url=jdbc:mysql://url/db_name
tomcat.jdbc.pool.username=username
tomcat.jdbc.pool.password=password
tomcat.jdbc.pool.initial-size=10
tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-on-borrow=true
tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-while-idle=true
tomcat.jdbc.pool.validation-query=SELECT 1
tomcat.jdbc.pool.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
tomcat.jdbc.pool.max_size=30
tomcat.jdbc.pool.min_size=7
```

I then created the following configuration class to setup my primary datasource as a org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.max_size}")
    private int maxSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.min_size}")
    private int minSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.initial-size}")
    private int initialSize;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-on-borrow}")
    private boolean testOnBorrow;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.test-while-idle}")
    private boolean testWhileIdle;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${tomcat.jdbc.pool.validation-query}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxSize);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(minSize);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And voila, I now have a production-ready connection pool.

I read that HikariCP would probably outperform tomcat-jdbc on some occasions BUT my app is a custom request from a business and it would only be used by 5-10-20 people at a time so ease of configuration and setup definitely outweighed the minuscule performance gains.

Hope this helps someone.