# MySQL code that I try to run on RDS gets a syntax error, but in a syntax checker for the same version, it runs fine

Tags: mysql, double-quotes, ansi-sql, sql-mode

So I have an AWS RDS instance with a MySQL 5.6.37 engine, and I'm checking the syntax of my code on sqlfiddle.com with mySQL version 5.6.

The code I put in sqlfiddle is

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher_Times(
  TEACHER_ID TEXT,
  BEG_TIME TIME,
  END_TIME TIME,
  DAYS VARCHAR(9) DEFAULT "MTWRF",
  TYPE VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT "unavailable");
```

The code I have that connects to the rds is using jdbc configured very similarly to this guy's stack overflow post: [Not able to set spring.datasource.type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833641/not-able-to-set-spring-datasource-type)

In my code I have

```
    result =
            "CREATE TABLE Teacher_Times(\n" +
            "   TEACHER_ID TEXT,\n" +
            "   BEG_TIME TIME,\n" +
            "   END_TIME TIME,\n" +
            "   DAYS VARCHAR(9) DEFAULT \"MTWRF\",\n" +
            "   TYPE VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT \"unavailable\");";
    jdbc_t.execute(result);
    result = "";
```

This general format for making queries has works in a bunch of other places, and I don't know if the AWS stuff is even relevant.

The exact error is "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"MTWRF"' at line 5"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode is enabled. I can reproduce the error with

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
```

http://rextester.com/JXV28208

Try using single quotes instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher_Times(
  TEACHER_ID TEXT,
  BEG_TIME TIME,
  END_TIME TIME,
  DAYS VARCHAR(9) DEFAULT 'MTWRF',
  TYPE VARCHAR(11) DEFAULT 'unavailable');
```

Comment: When I use single quotes the error doesn't change.  It even expresses the error as being near '"MTWRF"' which still has double quotes

Comment: @AviRudich Don't you find that strange? Try this `DAYS VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "if_you_do_not_see_this_in_the_error_message_then_you_are_executing_something_else"`

Comment: I did that, and I saw that error message.  All I can think of is that jdbc.execute() might be replacing the single quote for me

Comment: And just for kicks I tried setting sql_mode to '', and it didn't change anything

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with JDBC. Disabling ANSI_QUOTES [works here](http://rextester.com/CCQGQ95670).

Comment: Edit: I got it to start working.  Before I was only replacing the double quotes on MTWRF to see if the error would move to the lower line, but it the error stayed on MTWRF until I replaced the TYPE field default with quotes too.

Comment: Well.. strange. I guess JDBC has some  logic to determine which mode to use. When it sees double quotes in the query, it replaces all single quotes. Just a guess.